# Get a common element value from a complex XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm dealing with a XML file that has a very nested structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <Stuff>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceAlpha</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceAlpha25367</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceAlpha</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceAlpha25368</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceAlpha</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceAlpha25371</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceAlpha</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceAlpha25372</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceBeta</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceBeta25376</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceBeta</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceBeta25377</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceBeta</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceBeta25381</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceBeta</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceBeta25384</ID>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Consumable">
            <CalledAs>ResourceBeta</CalledAs>
            <ID>ResourceBeta25388</ID>
        </Item>

        <Item Class="Construct">
            <Named>ClosedFolders</Named>
            <ID>ClosedFolders25393</ID>
            <StorageCabinet>(102, 0, 94)</StorageCabinet>
            <AssignedTo>Colonist</AssignedTo>
            <Assigned Class="Consumable">
                <CalledAs>ResourceBeta</CalledAs>
                <ID>ResourceBeta25238</ID>
            </Assigned>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Construct">
            <Named>ClosedFolders</Named>
            <ID>ClosedFolders25394</ID>
            <StorageCabinet>(105, 0, 95)</StorageCabinet>
            <AssignedTo>Colonist</AssignedTo>
        </Item>
        <Item Class="Construct">
            <Named>ClosedFolders</Named>
            <ID>ClosedFolders25395</ID>
            <StorageCabinet>(103, 0, 92)</StorageCabinet>
            <AssignedTo>Colonist</AssignedTo>
            <Assigned Class="Consumable">
                <CalledAs>ResourceAlpha</CalledAs>
                <ID>ResourceBeta45232</ID>
            </Assigned>         
        </Item>

    </Stuff>
</Root>
```

Now, I need to get a list of all `ID` so that when I add a new `Consumable` or `Assigned`, I can generate (and make sure it's a unique) new Id.

Here is how I'm loading the file:

```
    String savefile = Settings.Default.SelectedSaveFilePath;

    var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.Load(savefile);

    var selectSingleNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/Root/Stuff/Item[@Class='Consumable']");
    if (selectSingleNode != null)
    {
      // Attempt to loop
    }
```

Now, at the level of `/Root/Stuff/Item[@Class='Consumable']`, I'm good for getting the `<ID>` but there is a nesting at `/Root/Stuff/Item[@Class='Construct']` that require sort of sub-for-each to get the `<ID>` of the `<Assigned Class="Consumable">`

I'm trying to generate a list of all the `<ID>` nodes in the whole document and if possible, a *Collection of Key-Value* where `<ID>` is value and Element (of whom `<ID>` belongs to) as Key.

I also know that the `<ID>` are unique in the document regardless of their parent. So I can directly find any element by searching just the ID.

I hope this make more sense.

Thanks.

Comment: A list of all the ID element values? Okay, that sounds reasonably straightforward - but you'll learn more if you try to find the answer for yourself. What have you already tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: Cant make the path. The given example is very simple. Actual data is over 25 MB of XML and sensitive so I;m not pasting.

Comment: What do you mean by "make the path"? Are you able to at least load the document in LINQ to XML? I didn't ask for the actual data...

Comment: Updated the question. It's 2:36 AM here. I'm a little slow. Sorry.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using XPath at all, to be honest - I'd just use Elements, Descendants etc. It's also unclear what the XPath expressions you've given in the code have to do with the XML you've given.

Comment: And why did you use the linq-to-xml tag when you're not using LINQ to XML?

Comment: I had the tag for LINQ to XML suggestions but realized after the first few answers that I'm changing a lot.

Comment: Well is there any reason *not* to use LINQ to XML?

Comment: The path makes sense as in abstracting a particular element among a lot of element with different number of child element BUT always having <ID>

Comment: It makes no sense for the XML you've given. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and improve your question. Ideally give a *representative* piece of XML (it doesn't need to contain sensitive data) and a short but complete program which doesn't work, explaining in what way it doesn't work. At the moment the information you've given is too vague (and unstable!) for us to help you.

Comment: I have edited the question a lot, Jon Skeet. Kindly let the question stay if it meets the requirements. I'm getting a lot of positive replies.

Comment: That's definitely better, although you still don't have any code showing how you're *trying* to find the IDs, and you haven't answered the question about whether you could use LINQ to XML instead. Not sure what you mean by "a lot of positive replies" as there haven't been any other comments or answers since you edited...

Comment: The replies that are already present even before the first edit... they hinted at what you were asking me: Linq to XML. The XDocument way helps a lot. However, most code us already written before and uses a weird mix of just about everything related to .NET and XML. I'm cleaning in at least the new methods.

Comment: I'm definitely going to go the way of Linq2XML. And I'm currently trying out how it'l help me retrieving the IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to get all Id's, and when you want to add new item you need to check if there is an item exist with the given id ?

```
var idList = XDocument.Load("path")
                      .Descendants("ID")
                      .Select(x => (string)x);

if(idList.Contains(givenId))
{ 
    ...
}
```

Or use a `HashSet` for faster search:

```
 var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(idList);
 if(hashSet.Contains(givenId)) 
 {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: And if I'm loading XML as: 
`var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();`
`xmlDocument.Load(savefile);`

I.e, not using `XDocument`?

Comment: you can do it but `LINQ to XML` is better and easy to use

Answer (score 1):

You can use HashSet for fast lookup

```
var ids = new HashSet<string>( 
                XDocument.Load(filename)
                    .Descendants("ID")
                    .Select(x => (string)x));
```

or (using XmlDocument class as in your edit).

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(filename);
var ids = new HashSet<string>(
                xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("ID")
                    .Cast<XmlNode>()
                    .Select(x => x.InnerText));
```