# How can I use the classes and the XSD to create new/modify/remove elements from the existing XML file by always modifying that file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-xml

I have recently being working on some XML reading/writing software and have asked around two question relating to that:[Get a common element value from a complex XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21418258/481656) and [Add to a collection where is XElement(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21501466/481656)

Now, I recieved exact help that I required but have realized that it's is quite hard to managed the actual file without... well managed code.

I'm using Linq2XML and have just spent an hour to get me a XSD generated for my XML and have generated a .cs file(s) form the XSD.

Now, I need to use these all together for my advantage.

How can I use the classes and the XSD to create new/modify/remove elements from the existing XML file by always modifying that file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there a pretty good samples on how to use Linq2XML in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb738045) to create new/modify/remove elements .

Hope that helps

Comment: Looking at that as we speak. I kept getting results to generate XML. I want to edit existing XML with a XSD and generated classes